# Prove that a group $G$ is Abelian if and only if $(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Prove that a group $G$ is Abelian if and only if $(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1} \forall a,b \in G$

Since G is a group then that means that it contains the following properties: Associativity, Identity, and Inverse.

To show that $G$ is abelian, then $ab=ba, \forall a,b \in G$

Would it be something like this?

$(ab)(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}(ab)\\
(ab)(ab)^{-1}=e\\
\rightarrow a^{-1}(ab)(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}e\\ \rightarrow (a^{-1}a)b(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}
\\ \rightarrow b(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}
\\ \rightarrow b^{-1}b(ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1} \rightarrow (ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1} $ Or did I went the wrong direction?

Comment: The first line looks to be backwards.  The $(ab)^{-1}$ appears to move from the right of $(ab)$ to the left of $(ab)$.  Many of your computations don't look like the follow each other.  Does the second line follow from the first line or is that just a fact?

Comment: $a^{-1}*a$ and $b^{-1}*b $would equal the identity, that's why i put e on the second line.

Comment: Since the claim is an "if and only if", you really need to prove both directions. One of them, however, is very straightforward.

Comment: well $(ab)^{-1} $is just simply $a^{-1}b^{-1}$, which would then make it as $a^{-1}b^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}.$ right?

Comment: The second line starts with an arrow, which often means "implies from the previous line."  In this case, you're introducing a new fact and the "implies" confuses the issue

Comment: My bad, let me edit it out.

Comment: We can't say that $(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$ unless we know that $a$ and $b$ commute. We *can* say that $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$, which is true for any two elements in any group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$ 
ab=ba 
\overset{\small{\text{by inversing}}}{\Longleftrightarrow} 
b^{-1}a^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1} 
\Longleftrightarrow 
(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1} 
.
$$

Comment: So you simply just substitute a with $a^{-1}
$, and b with$ b^{-1}$?

Comment: Since the property is true for all elements of the group, it is, in particular, true for the elements $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$, so yes, you can just replace the elements (after thinking about it in the right way).

Comment: @Killercamin ; Dear Killercamin, notice that always we have : $(xy)^{-1}=y^{-1}x^{-1}$. [Notice that 
$(xy)y^{-1}x^{-1}=\big( (xy)y^{-1} \big)  x^{-1}= \big( x \big) x^{-1}=1 $.]

Answer (score 2):

This is really a long comment, but let me get you started.

Easy direction: If $G$ is abelian, then $(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$.

Hints: Use the fact that $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$ and that $G$ is abelian to prove this.

Harder direction: If $(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$ for all $a,b$, then $G$ is abelian.

Hints: Start with the two equations $(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$ (given) and $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$ (always true).  Then, the right-hand-sides are equal, so $a^{-1}b^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$.  Now, perform some manipulations to reach $ab=ba$.

Answer (score 2):

For the backwards direction, here is a very short proof:

The hypothesis is 
$(ab)(a^{-1}b^{-1})=e$, so $\;(ab)a^{-1}=eb=b\;$ and finally $\; ab=ba$.

Answer (score 2):

Another short proof:
$$
ab=((ab)^{-1})^{-1}=(a^{-1}b^{-1})^{-1}=(b^{-1})^{-1}(a^{-1})^{-1}=ba.
$$

Comment: This might sound dumb, and sorry if it is, but where do you get the outside $()^{-1}$ part?

Comment: $x=(x^{-1})^{-1}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $G$ be a group with identity $e$ and let $a,b \in G$ be given.

First assume $G$ is Abelian. We want to prove $(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$. Group inverses are unique, so it suffices to show $(ab)(a^{-1}b^{-1})=e$. Since groups are associative, this is equivalent to showing $(a)(b)(a^{-1})(b^{-1})=e$. Since $G$ is Abelian, this can be re-written as $(a)(a^{-1})(b)(b^{-1})=(aa^{-1})(bb^{-1})=(e)(e)=e$ as required.

Next assume $(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$. We want to prove $G$ is Abelian; that is $ab=ba$. By assumption, we have $(ab)(a^{-1}b^{-1})=e$. By associativity, we have $(aba^{-1})(b^{-1})=e$. Since group inverses are unique, this implies $aba^{-1}=b$. Multiplying by $a$ on the right, we see $(aba^{-1})a=(b)a$ and so $(ab)(a^{-1}a)=ba$ and finally $(ab)(e)=ab=ba$ as required.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose G is abelian, then

$(a b)(a^{-1} b^{-1})\\ 
= a b a^{-1} b^{-1}\\ 
= a a^{-1} \ b b^{-1} \\
= e$

Thus, $(ab)^{-1} = a^{-1} b^{-1}.$

---

Now for the other way round, let $(ab)^{-1} = a^{-1} b^{-1}$, then

$a^{-1} b^{-1} \ a b = e $

Premultiplying by a,

$ b^{-1} \ a b = ae $

Premultiplying by b,

$ab = ba$

Thus G is abelian.